# Instance Allocated in Heap But Return As Reference

Tags: c++

Im just confused, I saw some code like this,

```
CFoo& fmethod()
{
    static CFoo *pfoo = new CFoo;

    return *pfoo
}
```

Is there a memory leak here? When the pfoo will be deleted?

Comment: It looks like the code is intentionally leaking the object because it's supposed to be a singleton, ie. it stays alive for the lifetime of the program anyways. But more context would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a memory leak here? When the `pfoo` will be deleted?

The answer depends on the caller: it is up to the caller to receive the result by reference or by pointer, and call the `delete`. If you do it like this, there's no leak

```
CFoo& x(fmethod());
delete &x; // No leak
CFoo* y = &fmethod();
delete y; // No leak
```

If you do it like this

```
CFoo x(fmethod()); // Memory leak
```

there's a leak of the return value of `fmethod()`.

It goes without saying that all of the above is rather unnatural, and should therefore be avoided.

**NOTE :** (in response to a comment about `pfoo` being function-`static`) Also note that since `pfoo` is function-static, the allocation happens only once. The deletion needs to happen only once as well. A typical pattern to follow in this situation is using a smart pointer instead of a regular one, like this:

```
CFoo& fmethod()
{
    static std::unique_ptr<CFoo> pfoo(new CFoo);

    return *(pfoo.get());
}
```

If you do it like that, the leak would be eliminated automatically by the smart pointer, and the callers would not need to think about deleting the object.

Comment: `pfoo` is `static` inside the function, you're actually advising to double delete... o_O

Comment: @syam You're right, that's an important thing to note. I added an implementation that fixes the leak using a smart pointer. Thanks for the note!